# Django. How I can update all sessions?

Tags: django

I create simple study app: columns with `Status` model and `Tasks` model within them, like trello.com.

I use Ajax call for updating page to single user, when I drag-n-drop task to other status column. Question is, how I can update elements for all sessions?

I need some external things or I can do it on django only?

Sorry if my question too broad, I'm not asking to write code for me, I just looking for advice.

Comment: If you want to update other user's browser, you will need some real-time app, you could check at [SwampDragon](http://swampdragon.net/)

Comment: @Gocht thank you, I will check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard Django Session model:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

all_sessions = Session.objects.all()
all_current_sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__lte=timezone.now())

# What fields are available in sessions? 
print(Session._meta.fields)
# Standard would be - (<django.db.models.fields.CharField: session_key>, <django.db.models.fields.TextField: session_data>, <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: expire_date>

for session in all_sessions:
    session_data = session.get_decoded()
    print(session_data)
```

In order to write to session_data, you need to re-encode `session_data`. See this [great post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/06/29/django-sessions-part-ii-how-sessions-work) for info on that.

**EDIT**: To add to this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656333/modify-session-data-of-different-django-user) that shows how to use `SessionStore` to re-encode Session data.

From the linked answer -

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore

# look up our sessions in session store
for session_key in logged_in:
    s = SessionStore(session_key=session_key)
    s['test'] = True
    s.save()
    s.modified
    # True
```

Comment: It is cool, but I think it not solve my problem. Maybe my question was incorect, my problem is: when someone change dom element, I want to update this changes for all sessions, without load page, realtime

Comment: Since modern Django base64 encodes each session dictionary, you would have to decode and recode each session record; that's a LOT of overhead and not practical. If you want to have a common variable shared across ALL sessions, why not store in a database, triggered by someone's click, and use AJAX to retrieve it? I don't understand the end goal here, but sessions seem to be a very obtuse way to go about it.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciated your help. I build it in `SwampDragon`

Comment: Very cool, looking into SwampDragon myself and it's very, very enticing so far! Didn't have prior knowledge of it before this. Thanks!

Comment: thank to @Gocht, he said about this cool thing in comment to answer :)