# Set variable to an expired session out of a view in Django

Tags: python, django, session-variables

I’m trying to set a variable to an **expired session** out of a view in Django.

I’m aware of django’s documentation on [Using sessions out of views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views). But in my case, I try to set a session variable in a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Here’s what I tried :

```python
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "My custom command."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for s in Session.objects.all():
            s['my_variable'] = None
```

What I get is this error:

```
TypeError: 'Session' object does not support item assignment
```

I also tried:

```python
[…]
ss = SessionStore(session_key=s.session_key)
ss['my_variable'] = None
ss.save()
```

This creates another session but does not modify the existing one…

How can I set `my_variable` to `None` ?

**Edit: The session I’m trying to set a variable to is expired**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify session data of different Django user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656333/modify-session-data-of-different-django-user)

Comment: try `s.get_decoded()['my_variable'] = None` ... `s` is a `Session` model instance which is different to the session store object (from `SessionBase` - not a model class)

Comment: How are you identifying the specific session where the variable should be set?

Comment: @JohnGordon For the moment, I just try to set a variable to all sessions, but of course It will be some specific sessions in some cases…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t do that on expired sessions. Django does not allow you.

But here is a hack:

```python
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "My custom command."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        future = datetime.datetime(datetime.MAXYEAR, 1, 1)
        for s in Session.objects.all():
            ed = s.expire_date
            s.expire_date = future
            s.save()
            ss = SessionStore(session_key=s.session_key)
            ss['my_variable'] = None
            ss.save()
            updated_session = Session.objects.get(session_key=s.session_key)
            updated_session.expire_date = ed
            updated_session.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "My custom command."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        store_cls = Session.get_session_store_class()
        for session in Session.objects.all():
            s = store_cls(session.session_key)
            s['my_variable'] = None
            # so that any subsequent code which reads from the session sees your change
            s.save()
```

The code is loading saved session data from the db, but as `Session` model instances.

These are not the same as the session objects you get back from the `SessionStore` in the code shown at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views

We actually don't really want to deal with `Session` model instances at all, what we need is the `session_key` from the instance, so that we can instantiate the session store.

We can then update the value in session object via `__setitem__` and save it back into the db https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py#L73 (until we do that our change won't be visible to any other code that tries to read the session data).

Since we only need the `session_key` we can amend the code above:

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "My custom command."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        store_cls = Session.get_session_store_class()
        for session_key in Session.objects.values_list("session_key", flat=True):
            s = store_cls(session_key)
            s['my_variable'] = None
            # so that any subsequent code which reads from the session sees your change
            s.save()
```

Comment: I’m getting `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'` on `s.save()`

Comment: @Zatigem ah, it was more complicated than I realised, have updated with working code

Comment: The updated code has same problem that when I tried with `SessionStore()`. It just creates another session but does not modify the existing one…